# Submit form using a href a long with validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with this small script.
I have a list with products. Each product can be added to cart from this list.

But I need to validate that variants is choosen. 
The validation is working okay, but the submit do not.

**JS**:

```
function submitForm() {
    if ($('#variants').val() !== '') {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    } else {
        alert("You need to pick variant");
    }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="form" action="FormPost.aspx">
    <select name="variants" id="variants" class="variants">
        <option value="">Select variant</option>   
        <option value="Black">Black</option>
        <option value="White">White</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
    </select>
    <a href="javascript:submitForm();" class="addToCart buybtn_small text-left pull-right">Buy</a>
</form>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pthv/k3zmon2d/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always try to make your scripts [unobtrusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). 
Use jQuery's [**`.click()`**](https://api.jquery.com/click/) method instead:

```
$('.addToCart').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).closest('form');

    // to access the select by tag name:
    if (form.find('select').val()) {

    // to access the select by class:
    // if (form.find('.variants').val()) {

        form.submit();
    } else {
        alert("You need to pick variant");
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="form" action="FormPost.aspx">
    <select name="variants" id="variants" class="variants">
        <option value="">Select variant</option>   
        <option value="Black">Black</option>
        <option value="White">White</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
    </select>
    <a href="#" class="addToCart buybtn_small text-left pull-right">Buy</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Well, there a little issue. It validates the first form all the time.
What I needed is the script to validate the form that is being used. Can you help?

Comment: @pth, it's because you're accessing your `select` element by `id` attribute - `'#variants'`. The `id` attribute **MUST** be unique for each element in the DOM (so, you can't have two `selects` with the same `id` attribute). You should get the `select` value of the current form by using either `class` or `tag` name. See updated answer.

Comment: okay thanks. That solved that. 
But it's not all the forms that have variants though, but it validates anyway.

Comment: @pth , well... You should always post in your question as much details as you can to describe the problem. Noone really knows how the other forms looks like.

Comment: Yep. You are right. I'm sorry - keep it in mind. 
Can you help again you think. I need somehow to check if .variants are present for each form. And only validate the forms where it is. Otherwise the form should submit. Tried with a for each but that didn't turn out right.

Comment: You can use this:

`if (!form.find('.variants').length || form.find('.variants').val()) {`

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is not finding your form, use this instead:

```
$('form#form').submit();
```

Here's an updated fiddle, tweaked to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/y5ytrcuq/

(I added jquery reference, made your `submit` function part of `window`, and changed the above line)

Comment: Okay. 
But it turns out that is choosing the first select every time. I have multiple products  on the same page. So it should only choose the form that is being used

Comment: Give your forms different ids?

Comment: I've just tried that. But it's same result. 
If I click on product 3 it's the first product that is being validated?

Comment: if you're calling the same submit function every time, pass the id of the form you want to submit as a parameter and use that

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [jQuery .submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) method and a submit button. A submit button is the standardized way to... submit a form, it's better for semantic and accessibility.

This method detects when the form is submitted using the submit button (better than just detecting the click on a link, and especially better than putting code in the href attribute).
You can pass it a function that does the checking. And you use the `preventDefault()` method of the event to cancel the submitting :

```
$( "#form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  if($("variants").val() == "")
  {
    //Something is wrong, display a warning and stop the submit action
    alert("You need to chose a variant")
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  //Everything is ok, the submit action happens normally
});
```

If `event.preventDefault();` isn't called the form is submitted normally. It will be easier to change your code for multiple forms if you don't have to find the one that was clicked.
Here is the JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/k3zmon2d/3/